# What shall be declared in android manifest?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have tried to seek for some article about recommended (or "required") elements of **AndroidManifest.xml** file. Is there some sort of to-do list like that?

According to my brief experience I would include `<application>`, all existing `<activity>`, `<service>` etc. definitions + `<uses-sdk>` part. What else?

Comment: Um, well, what's required depends substantially on what your app is.

Comment: have you seen http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html?

Comment: ofc I have...but I found "look what this file can do" stuff rather than "necessary core" definition...

Comment: I would like to know stuff, that is really common across various applications...however, the statement, that there is nothing like this at all, is also desirable output of my little research...

Comment: I think you should add the stuff that you need... Don't add a lot of things that you don't even know what they are used for... This way, you avoid unpredictable behaviors... So, add  things as soon as you start to need it and nothing more